# Best way to handle per user Settings in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm developing an application in Rails 3. In the application, users are allowed to send e-mails using their existing email account settings. What's the best approach to define per user settings for every user's credentials?

Regards,
Liviu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you'd probably want to offer the option for users to change/update their settings, they should go in a model. After that, it comes down to taste...

If you have only a few settings, you could store them directly in the User model. If you have lots of settings, you could have a separate UserProfile model that `belongs_to` User.